# Находим предыдущий месяц

Tags: google-apps-script

При проверке отладчиком в редакторе проекта, вычисляет верное значение. Но как только я проверяю работу скрипта уже в процессе выполнения, записывает в ячейку вот такой результат: #NUM!
Помогите разобраться в чем моя ошибка.

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp;        
var sheet = app.openById('****');
var list2 = sheet.getSheetByName('Финальная'); 

var date2 = new Date();
date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() - 1);
var datenew = date2.toLocaleDateString();
var dates = new Date(datenew);
var mon = dates.getMonth() + 1; // Записываем предыдущий месяц

Logger.log(mon);

list2.getRange(3,6).setValue(mon);
```

[image: Вот что я получаю в отладчике и при выполнении триггера]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно найти значение предыдущего месяца от текущей даты. Так вот, в режиме отладки в переменную mon попадает правильное значение и это значение без труда записывается в таблицу. Но как только я заставляю скрипт работать от триггера, то получаю вот такое значение в ячейке моей таблицы: #NUM!
Не могу понять причину такого поведения.

Comment: Приведите [достаточно полный пример](https://contributor.pw/post/why-you-should-create-an-example/). Если вы не понимаете, видя весь проект, как остальные должны понять, смотря на это?

Comment: @contributorpw поправил свой пример и добавил скрин из журнала.